# Entity Framework query returns entity that doesn't meet condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a following code:

```
Book book1 = await DbContext.Set<Book>().Where(x => x.Code == 1).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
book1.Code = 2;

DbContext.Entry<Book>(book1).State = EntityState.Modified

//This returns book, where book2.Code == 2
Book book2 = await DbContext.Set<Book>().Where(x => x.Code == 1).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

//This returns null
Book book3 = await DbContext.Set<Book>().Where(x => x.Code == 2).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

And I think I have a clue why this happens: Query goes to database, grabs book where `Code == 1` a gets it (`DbContext.SaveChanges()` has not been called yet). Then entity gets to `ChangeTracker` which finds that there is another entity with the same `Id` (but different `Code`), merges these 2 object into single one and returns it. Thus the returned entity has `Code == 2`.

My question is whether is there a way to prevent this behavior, ie. I want `DbContext` to return entities satisfying the query condition no matter they are taken from database or being tracked by `ChangeTracker`.

(Using Entity Framework 6.2.0)

Comment: To avoid this behavior - don't reuse EF context.

Comment: Consider to use [AsNoTracking()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn237200%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) to avoid caching entities

Comment: @Evk I want to execute this code in a single transaction (where I have single `DbContext`). I think it is not a good idea to dispose context after each query/update...

Comment: If your code conceptually represents single operation - then it's ok to use one `DbContext`. But it's generally _is_ a good idea to dispose context as soon as possible, it costs almost nothing (since database connections are pooled). Transaction can be achieved with `TransactionScope` if you use multiple contexts. Anyway - as far as I know this behavior is by design and there is no way around it (AsNoTracking might help, but not sure if it fits your case).

Comment: Your code is quite strange conceptually by the way. First you query entity A and modify it, then you query the same entity A and want to have it in unmodified state (as in database). Now you have two objects representing the same database entity, one of which is modified and the other is not (if you apply AsNoTracking to second query - it will be the state). Doesn't look quite right to me.

Comment: @Evk My real code is more complex, I made it simple (and stupid) to explain the gist. (In a real world, the second query is based on a different condition which, however, also returns the modified entity. 

About context disposing: This happens inside an ASP.NET Core MVC app and I use one context per web request. Until now I never doubt it was a good design...

Comment: Yes that's usually considered good design (though I myself prefer to manage creation of context myself even in web applications because I fed up with issues like this one, but that's an exception). All in all you now know the options you have - AsNoTracking, using different contexts. By the way: EF does not "merges these 2 objects into 1" - it just uses object already existing in change tracker and throws away object it got from database.

Comment: "it just uses object already existing in change tracker and throws away object it got from database" - that's not quite true. The tracking of entries in the dbSets of the context allows EF to "reuse" results of previous queries, if the underlying database has not changed (by EF means, that is SaveChanges() with added/deleted/modified entries). This also means it does not need to get any object from the database - the context's log will claim another query was sent, but the query is never executed, but calculated from the LINQ call and matched to the prefetched result.